# How to write a custom shortcode name book?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

```
<?php




add_shortcode('Book','book_shortcode_templete');

function book_shortcode_templete($atts, $content)
{

  $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'id'          => 0,
            'author_name' => '',
            'publisher'   => '',
            'year'        => 0000,
            'tag'         => '',
            ''    => '',
        ],
        $atts,
        'book'
    );



if ($attributes['category'] != "" || $attributes["tag"] != "") {
    $args = [
        'p'              => $attributes['id'],
        'post_type'      => 'book',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'tax_query'      => [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'taxonomy'         => 'Book Category',
                'field'            => 'slug',
                'terms'            => explode(',', $attributes['category']),
                'include_children' => true,
                'operator'         => 'IN',
            ],
            [
                'taxonomy'         => 'Book Tag',
                'field'            => 'slug',
                'terms'            => explode(',', $attributes['tag']),
                'include_children' => false,
                'operator'         => 'IN',
            ],
        ],
    ];
} else if ($attributes['author_name'] != "" || $attributes["publisher"] != "" || $attributes["year"] != "") {
   
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'book',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
       
        'meta_query'     => [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key'     => 'book_author',
                'value'   => explode(',', $attributes['author_name']),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ],
            [
                'key'     => 'book_publisher',
                'value'   => explode(',', $attributes['publisher']),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ],
            [
                'key'     => 'book_published_date',
                'value'   => explode(',', $attributes['year']),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ],
        ],
    ];
} else {
    $args = [
        'p'              => $attributes['id'],
        'post_type'      => 'book',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        
    ];
}//end if

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts() == true) {
    while ($query->have_posts() == true) {
        $query->the_post();
       
      $price      = get_metadata('book', get_the_ID(), 'book_price', true);


        // Iterate post index in loop.
        $content .= '<article id="Book-'.get_the_ID().'">';
        $content .= '<center><h3 style="color: maroon;">'.get_the_title().'</h3></center>';
        $content .= '<p>'.get_the_content().'</p>';
      $content .= '<p>Author :- '.get_metadata('book', get_the_ID(), 'author_name', true);
        $content .= '<br> publisher :- '.get_metadata('book', get_the_ID(), 'book_publisher', true);
        $content .= '<br> year :- '.get_metadata('book', get_the_ID(), 'book_published_date', true);
       $content .= '<br> price :- ' .$price ;
        $content .= '<br> URL :- <a href='.get_metadata('book', get_the_ID(), 'book_url', true).'>'.get_metadata('book', get_the_ID(), 'book_url', true).'</a>';
        $content .= '</article>';
    }//end while
} else {
    $content .= "No Book Found....";
}

return $content;
return $attributes;


}
```

Comment: What is a "shortcode name book"?

Answer (score 0):

hmm ok I see what you are trying to do. Ok no problem I can help.
Use the following site to create a short code by generating the function for a short code then adding the code it generates to your functions.php file:
https://generatewp.com/shortcodes/

As long as you fill in book on each code generator with “book” and the information it asks for it will create the post type and the short code for you.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your support. i generate this code but i  want dynamic output of author,publisher,year,price and url. but i can't fetch it ...

Comment: Yes ok that other data you want to store for each book is post metadata.  Adding places to store all that is a different and more complicated question.  This has answered the question you asked but that is something else.

Comment: yes i want to store that data for each book ...and want to show with the help of shortcode.

Comment: this is my assignment https://learn.rtcamp.com/topic/plugin-development-assignment/         i am on creating shortcode step.please help me

Comment: you can find my project on github hvsr26

Comment: The assignment instructions say that the next step is to a) add post metadata for each book or b) to create the settings page.  You can choose either option, it does not matter the order for now.